# How do I configure an ER-X to prioritize certain machines and services?

Tags: networking, qos

I have an ER-X (running v2.0.8) that is load-balancing two 16/1 DSL lines.

I also have a lot of kids and Apple devices!

I'm constantly getting ping spikes and other symptoms of buffer bloat and lag. The worst situation is usually at the kids' bedtime when all the Apple devices get plugged into chargers. (Apple, in its wisdom, decided to not provide any configuration for when to backup to iCloud and instead will just start doing it when the screen is locked and the device is charging.)

I currently have Smart Queues on the upload for both DSL lines (eth0 and eth1) set to 90% of my bandwidth. Unfortunately, iCloud backups consume all available upload bandwidth so gaming still suffers.

My end goal is to ensure my PS4 (and my work laptop) take priority over all other traffic.

How do I accomplish this?